# Adding two additional values to enum flags

Tags: c#

Is there a limit to the number values I can add here?

```
public enum AssignmentType
{
    None = 0,
    Attendant = 1,
    ConductorCBS = 2,
    ReaderCBS = 4,
    Chairman = 8,
    Mike = 16,
    PlatformAttendant = 32,
    Prayer = 64,
    OCLM = 128,
    Sound = 256,
    Student = 512,
    Custom = 1024,
    Demonstration = 2048,
    Assistant = 4096
}
```

I want to two more values, which I assume should be double:

- 8192
- 16384

Is is Ok to extra my enum with these two additional values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do enums have a limit of members in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275578/do-enums-have-a-limit-of-members-in-c)

Comment: @funie200 That answer is a bit cryptic. Does my values fall within that limit?

Comment: The default underlying type of an enum is `int` so adding any valid `int` values like these  should be fine. That said this really looks like an enum that is intended to have the `FlagsAttribute` otherwise there is no gain by adding powers of 2

Comment: @Knoop It does have a `[Flags]` too. Just not in the code above.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Your values fall in the range of `int`, so yes, they should be fine. Good practice for this situation, just try it out

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's answer is a quick and simple documentation read away. IMHO, This is a very low quality question coming from a such a high-reputation (10K+) member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# and of course all .NET enums are by default `int` based.

Thus you can store values from -2 147 483 648 up to 2 147 483 647.

Below or above you need to specify another type like:

```
public enum AssignmentType : long or ulong
```

With `ulong` it is up to  18 446 744 073 709 551 615 !

Sometimes someone think using small types will optimize, but in fact it is not the case if less than 32bits on x32 systems or less than 64bits on x64 systems because of CPU architecture. Doing such thing, using a byte or a short for example, may only be usefull if having needs like working with an embedded system and/or using enums values in a buffer containing several data like in a binary struct/buffer.

If I remember, the first .NET Framework AnyCPU had `int` x32 or x64 depending of the platform, but next versions had set `int` as 4 bytes for all systems, that confused me... but it is comprehensible because of portability problems instead of portability advantages.

[Enumeration types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum)

[Integral numeric types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can it's no problem.

Check [enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum) official Microsoft documentation or I would suggest looking at [this](https://www.dotnetperls.com/enum) as well.

If you are wondering why are those values doubled, take a look at `FlagsAttribute` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=netcore-3.1). It gives you the opportunity to select multiple enum values at once.